# Header and menu width

Tags: html, css

Can I get some help on making my header and top menus the same width as my main wrapper?

Here's my site: soccer-mate.com

Here's what I have as custom CSS so far:

```
/* Structure */
#wrapper                { min-height: 100%; position: relative; padding: 0.5px 0 20px; }

#main                   { padding: 10px 10px 0; }

/* Header */
#header                 { min-width: 990px; padding: 0; }

#branding               { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }

.logo                   { max-width: 590px; float: left; padding: 30px 0 34px 10px; }

.blog-name              { margin: 0 0 3px; line-height: 1em; display: block; }

.blog-description       { line-height: 1em; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 3px 0 0; }



#top-menu, #nav  { min-width: 990px; }

#top-menu-content, #nav-content  { margin: 0 auto; width: 978px; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: can u give a working fiddle?

Comment: http://fiddlesalad.com/html/

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: @RajaSekar is referring to a working fiddle that demonstrates your problem.